# How to get original height and width of video strip in python?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, dimensions

Here is the context :
I call blender by the command line like so :
blender -b -P myscript.py

In the python script i am doing something simple, i add a movie strip with no sound and then print orignal size of the video:

```
bpy.ops.sequencer.movie_strip_add({'area': area},filepath='/tmp/file.mp4',frame_start=1, channel=1)

active_strip = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip

print(active_strip.elements[0].orig_height)

print(active_strip.elements[0].orig_width)
```

The problem is that i always get 0 for both height and width which is not the original dimension of the video.

When i execute this inside blender python console i get the right original dimensions.

Any ideas why it does'nt work by the command line?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that you have to show strip in the VSE viewport to get dimesions to work. Since there's no viewports in background mode, Blender can't update information about a strip you added. So you're getting zeros.

Comment: Pity we can't get it from blender in the background. Thanks. Finally I just used moviepy to gett hese data  and then send it to blender through the command line.